# Cant delete .vdi file

Tags: windows, virtualbox

Ok so i used virtualbox in windows and ran linux,i accidentally gave it 64gbs.
when i realized that it was dumb i uninstalled virtualbox and deleted the folder but i sill didnt get the 64 gbs back.
I've already tried searching for the .vdi file but i couldn't find it.
Can anybody tell me what to i have to do to get my 64 gbs back?
I've already asked these questions in reddit but nobody answered.
Need help!

Comment: You've deleted _what_ folder?

Comment: C:\Users\user name\.VirtualBox

Answer (score 0):

Virtual machines are by default stored in `C:\Users\<username>\VirtualBox VMs`. Each subdirectory corresponds to one VM.

You may have chosen any different path when creating the VM too.

Please note that uninstalling a program usually doesn't remove its files. This is the case not only for VirtualBox. You could have, however, right-clicked the VM in VirtualBox and selected *Remove*.

Comment: I removed it but i still have 930 gigs outa 1 tb

Comment: And theres no folders of virtualbox in my pc now

Comment: @JakeSparrow There's probably something else taking up space. Windows for example. VirtualBox doesn't grow VDIs to their max capacity by default. Creating a 64 GB VDI doesn't consume 64 GBs immediately.